# Using VPN in order to continue working from home?

Tags: vpn

Recently, I asked my manager is it possible for me to take my laptop home in order to work on a project that I've been involved for my company. I received an approval, however he mentioned that I'd need a VPN. Because he will be unavailable for contact during the following week because of some health issues, I can't consult with him about what is and how to setup a VPN so I can work on the software project from home.

Can someone please explain what is a VPN and is it possible for me to set it up from my home by using my company laptop?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Anyway, this is a question you should ask to your IT department. It is part of their job to set it up/guide you through it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can someone please explain what is a VPN ...

A VPN is a virtual private network, essentially a virtual network cable which allows you to be present in some remote network with your laptop without actually being physically present at the remote location.

> ... and is it possible for me to set it up from my home by using my company laptop?

In order to securely use a VPN into your company network the endpoint inside the companies network has to be setup by the IT department and they also need to install the necessary software to access the VPN on your laptop (or provide it to you) and provide you with the login credentials and also instructions on how to use the VPN. Depending on the security policy in your company there might also be additional restrictions on what you are allowed to do with the system when working from home.

Thus, contact your IT department for further instructions and help.